# How to unnest an array column in Snowflake database into multiple columns

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How to unnest a variant(array) column in Snowflake into multiple columns

column name: user;  table name: event;
the column name is a variant format

```
    [
      {
        "key": "user_id",
        "value": {
          "set_timestamp_micros": 1621804433449213,
          "string_value": "auth0|6094a88b602505006f20fc0e"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "env",
        "value": {
          "set_timestamp_micros": 1621804433445213,
          "string_value": "staging"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "first_open_time",
        "value": {
          "int_value": 1620248400000,
          "set_timestamp_micros": 1620245124142213
        }
      }
    ]
```

My objectives are to transpose like

| user_id | env |
| --- | --- |
| auth0|6094a88b602505006f20fc0e | staging |

I tried FLATTEN function, but it is not working as I expected.

Comment: Snowflake is not BigQuery so I fixed the tags.

Answer (score 1):

So FLATTEN on your JSON would give you access to the three sub objects of the array, but you are wanting to access two sub objects by name, if you have sets of there values/objects in your data, and they are all related via `set_timestamp_micros`, you could PIVOT after FLATTEN or you could MAX like

```
SELECT f.value:value:set_timestamp_micros::number as set_timestamp_micros
    ,max(iff(f.value:key = 'env', f.value:value:string_value::text, null)) as env
    ,max(iff(f.value:key = 'user_id', f.value:value:string_value::text, null)) as user_id 
    ,max(iff(f.value:key = 'first_open_time', f.value:value:int_value::number, null)) as first_open_time 
FROM data_table AS dt, 
 TABLE(FALTTEN(input=> dt.json)) f
GROUP BY set_timestamp_micros
ORDER BY set_timestamp_micros;
```

Answer (score 0):

Flatten just gives you access to the elements of the array.  Since the form of the JSON is key-value as separate attributes, you'll need to pivot after you flatten:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT parse_json('    [
      {
        "key": "user_id",
        "value": {
          "set_timestamp_micros": 1621804433449213,
          "string_value": "auth0|6094a88b602505006f20fc0e"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "env",
        "value": {
          "set_timestamp_micros": 1621804433445213,
          "string_value": "staging"
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "first_open_time",
        "value": {
          "int_value": 1620248400000,
          "set_timestamp_micros": 1620245124142213
        }
      }
    ]') as var
  ), z AS (
   SELECT y.value:key::string as key, y.value:value:string_value::string as value
   from x,
   lateral flatten(input=>var) y
  )
SELECT "'user_id'" as user_id, "'env'" as env
FROM z
PIVOT (MAX(value) FOR key IN ('user_id','env')) AS TMP;
```